# Inserting data into Global temporary table by executing Stored Procedure in SQLPLUS

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I creatd a stored procedure. And a global temporary table inside it. 
Now i am inserting data into this table by fatching cursor into local variables.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  "DEMO"  
(
PARM_YEAR IN NUMBER,    
PARM_PERIOD IN NUMBER, 
PARM_PERIOD_TYPE IN CHAR,
PARM_PERIOD_ROLL IN CHAR, 
PARM_TYPE IN VARCHAR2,
P_CURSOR IN OUT types.cursorType
)

IS

LOC_EXISTS NUMBER;

LOC_TYPE_PERIOD CHAR(2);
LOC_CURSOR_YEAR INTEGER;
LOC_CURSOR_PERIOD INTEGER;
LOC_CURSOR_TYPE_PERIOD CHAR(2 BYTE);
LOC_CURSOR_DEV_COPCL NUMBER(10,1); 
LOC_CURSOR_DIST_GRP  NUMBER(3,0);

CURSOR DIST_CHART IS


SELECT  X.YEAR , X.PERIOD, X.TYPE_PERIOD, X.COST AS DEV_COPCL

FROM
SMY_PRVDR_TYPE_PRVDR X;

BEGIN

/* Set Period type */

IF (PARM_PERIOD_TYPE = 'Q' AND PARM_PERIOD_ROLL = 'A') THEN
    LOC_TYPE_PERIOD := 'Q';
ELSE IF (PARM_PERIOD_TYPE = 'Q' AND PARM_PERIOD_ROLL = 'R') THEN
    LOC_TYPE_PERIOD := 'RQ';
ELSE IF (PARM_PERIOD_TYPE = 'M' AND PARM_PERIOD_ROLL = 'A') THEN
    LOC_TYPE_PERIOD := 'M';
ELSE
    LOC_TYPE_PERIOD := 'RM';


END IF;
END IF;
END IF;


 LOC_EXISTS := 0;
   SELECT 1 INTO LOC_EXISTS
     FROM ALL_TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%DEMO1%';

   IF LOC_EXISTS = 1 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE DEMO1';
END IF; 


OPEN DIST_CHART;

LOOP 

  FETCH DIST_CHART INTO LOC_CURSOR_YEAR, LOC_CURSOR_PERIOD, LOC_CURSOR_TYPE_PERIOD, 
   LOC_CURSOR_DEV_COPCL;

EXIT WHEN DIST_CHART%NOTFOUND;

SELECT DIST_GRP(LOC_CURSOR_DEV_COPCL) INTO LOC_CURSOR_DIST_GRP FROM DUAL;


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO DEMO1 VALUES  ('|| LOC_CURSOR_YEAR ||', '''|| 
LOC_CURSOR_PERIOD || ''', '''|| LOC_CURSOR_TYPE_PERIOD ||''', '|| LOC_CURSOR_DEV_COPCL 
||', '|| LOC_CURSOR_DIST_GRP || ')';

END LOOP;

CLOSE DIST_CHART;


 EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 LOC_EXISTS:=0;

  END;
```

Problem is that.. 
    When i am executing this stored procedure into sql developer data is inserted  successfuly into the global temporary table.

But

When i run same execute command into SQLPLUS,  procedure run successfully, but data is not inserted into the global temporary table.

Code of GTT is

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "ICUSER"."DEMO1" 
 (  "YEAR" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "PERIOD" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "TYPE_PERIOD" CHAR(2 BYTE), 
    "DEV_COPCL" NUMBER(*,1), 
    "DIST_GRP" NUMBER(3,0)
  ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;
```

Comment: how are you confirming that "data is not inserted into the global temporary table." when run from SQL*plus?

Comment: by Gathering statistics. Bcoz in oracle temporary table exists physically. And data exists till the session is alive.

Comment: okay, I'm not clear on how by gathering statistics you're convinced data isn't there. Would you mind editing that into your post?

Comment: by gathering statistics of table .. dont you get every information about table? or tell me what you are understading from the term "Gather Statistics"??

Comment: From what I remember, dbms_stats.gather_table_stats doesn't return any data. Which is why I'm asking how you determined that(tangential question would be why use such a convoluted method instead of straight query. Oh well).

Comment: Then you must know--> It will definatly return number of rows in the table. And you can simply conclude from there--> that is data is there in table or not.  do it in sql developer-->GUI tool

Comment: Is there some reason you can't execute `SELECT * FROM MY_GTT`?

Comment: Users have their own stratgies of  working. I want to know all about the table, so i am following this approach. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: The best way to identify if records got inserted into the GTT is to use `select count(1) from into <local_variable> DEMO1;` after `END LOOP` and print it out. It will clear all the doubts.